# sorting strings while using malloc

Tags: c, arrays, string, sorting

how can i sort the string without breaking the program? the string input had to be done without the use of gets(fgets , getsc etc.)

```
int main ()
{

    char **pointsarr;           
    char temp;

    printf("insert strings: \n");      
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("declare the size of the strings: \n");          

    pointsarr = malloc(a * sizeof(char*));         



    for (i=0; i<a; i++)
    {

        pointsarr[i]= malloc(b* sizeof(char));      
    }

    printf("input strings: \n");

    for (i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", pointsarr[i]);    
    }

    printf("the strings on the 2d board: \n");

    for (int i=0; i<a; i++)
    printf("%s\n",pointsarr[i]);

   /* int n= strlen(pointsarr);

    for (i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        {
            if (pointsarr[i]>pointsarr[j])
            {
                temp=pointsarr[i];
                temp=pointsarr[i];                      // whats going wrong on this point?
                pointsarr[i]=pointsarr[j];
                pointsarr[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
*/

    free(pointsarr);



}
```

in this if whats going wrong and it dosent return the sorted string?

Comment: What are `a` and `b`?  Neither of these is declared in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to sort your array is to use the library function `qsort()`.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int comparefunc (const void* p1, const void* p2)
{
    return strcmp (* (const char **) p1, * (const char **) p2);
}

int main ()
{
    int i, a = 4, b = 20;
    char **pointsarr = (char **) malloc(a * sizeof(char*));

    for (i=0; i<a; i++)
        pointsarr[i]= (char *) malloc(b* sizeof(char));      

    strcpy (pointsarr [0], "qwerty");
    strcpy (pointsarr [1], "uiop");
    strcpy (pointsarr [2], "asdf");
    strcpy (pointsarr [3], "ghjkl");

    for (i=0; i<a; i++)
        printf("%s\n",pointsarr[i]);
    printf("-----\n");

    qsort (pointsarr, a, sizeof (char **), comparefunc);

    for (i=0; i<a; i++)
        printf("%s\n",pointsarr[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
qwerty
uiop
asdf
ghjkl
-----
asdf
ghjkl
qwerty
uiop
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U1bsii9sJBS0hXpQ)

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: the line `int n= strlen(pointsarr);` is certainly wrong, as pointsarray is a pointer to an array of strings, not a pointer to a string.
It is also unnecessary, as you already have the length of the array: it's `a`.
Problem 2: see the comment by @xing